# Civix not working Joomla! 3.9.3

Tags: joomla, civix

Civix doesn't seem to work with Joomla! 3.9.3. According to [this](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/770-20190206-core-implement-the-typo3-phar-stream-wrapper.html), Joomla! 3.9.3 doesn't allow loading of phar packed files. When I try to run civix, I get the following exception error in a red panel:

[TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\Exception]
  Unexpected file extension in "phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/bin/api/class.api.php"

I reverted to Joomla! 3.9.2 and civix works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A bug report was filed in https://github.com/totten/civix/issues/147
2. The issue specifically affects the normal PHAR build. Running from git works, eg

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/totten/civix
   cd civix
   composer install
   export PATH="$PWD/bin:$PATH"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

OK, it looks like it's a problem with Joomla 3.9.3. See discussion [here](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/23956). Fix should be included in Joomla 3.9.4, which is out on 12th March.

Comment: No, the problem persists in Joomla 3.9.4.